# RDLC Design, A column of Row number showing extra value

Tags: rdlc

My rdlc report is working fine. but displaying 0 that i need to remove. please help. attached screenshot describe the design problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqVQF.png)

C# code

```
protected void GenerateReport()
{
    if (Request.QueryString["rdlcrepname"] != null)
    {
        reportName = Request.QueryString["rdlcrepname"].ToString();
        string strprm1 = Request.QueryString["prm1"].ToString();
        var strprm2 = Request.QueryString["param2"] != null ? Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["param1"].ToString()) : 0 ;
        SqlParameter[] clsParam = new SqlParameter[2];
        clsParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@param1", strprm1);
        clsParam[1] = new SqlParameter("@param2", strprm2);
        ds = dataAccess.GetDataSet("spname", clsParam);
        dsShow.Tables.Add();
        dsShow.Tables.Add("FinalDisplayDataHeader");
        dsShow.Tables.Add("FinalDisplayData");
        //DataColumns-Header SQL of Header
        dsShow.Tables["FinalDisplayDataHeader"].Columns.Add("col1", typeof(string));
        dsShow.Tables["FinalDisplayDataHeader"].Columns.Add("col2", typeof(string));
        dsShow.Tables["FinalDisplayDataHeader"].Columns.Add("col3", typeof(string));
        dsShow.Tables["FinalDisplayDataHeader"].Columns.Add("col4", typeof(string));
        //DataColumns SQL of data
        dsShow.Tables["FinalDisplayData"].Columns.Add("col1", typeof(string));
        dsShow.Tables["FinalDisplayData"].Columns.Add("col2", typeof(string));
        dsShow.Tables["FinalDisplayData"].Columns.Add("col3", typeof(string));

        if (ds.Tables["Table"].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["Table"].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                dsQPUDisplay.Tables["FinalDisplayDataHeader"].Rows.Add(); //Header
                dsShow.Tables["FinalDisplayDataHeader"].Rows[i]["col1"] = ds.Tables["Table"].Rows[i]["col1"].ToString();
                dsShow.Tables["FinalDisplayDataHeader"].Rows[i]["col2"] = ds.Tables["Table"].Rows[i]["col2"].ToString();
                dsShow.Tables["FinalDisplayDataHeader"].Rows[i]["col3"] = ds.Tables["Table"].Rows[i]["col3"].ToString();
                dsQPUDisplay.Tables["FinalDisplayDataHeader"].Rows[i]["col4"] = ds.Tables["Table"].Rows[i]["col4"].ToString();
                for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
                { 
                    dsShow.Tables["FinalDisplayData"].Rows.Add(); //Data
                    dsShow.Tables["FinalDisplayData"].Rows[k]["col1"] = ds.Tables["Table1"].Rows[k]["col1"].ToString();
                    dsShow.Tables["FinalDisplayData"].Rows[k]["col2"] = ds.Tables["Table1"].Rows[k]["col2"].ToString();//This is right
                    dsShow.Tables["FinalDisplayData"].Rows[k]["col3"] = ds.Tables["Table1"].Rows[k]["col3"].ToString();
                }
            }
                reportPath = string.Empty;
                rdlcReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = GetReportPath(reportName);
                //rdlcReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                ReportDataSource rdsHeader = new ReportDataSource("DataHeader", dsShow.Tables["FinalDisplayDataHeader"]);
                ReportDataSource rdsData = new ReportDataSource("Data", dsShow.Tables["FinalDisplayData"]);
                rdlcReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rdsQPUheader);
                rdlcReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rdsQPUData);
        }// for complete batch students loop closed
        rdlcReportViewer.DataBind();
        rdlcReportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
    }
}
```

RDLC is in design. code above give you idea how i am generating the rdlc report. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Y3wS.png) this link describe issue of **RowNumber** display

Comment: This is still not resolved by me. please help

Comment: Fixed of extra zero issue. Thanks a lot for reading my question and giving me support to work on this task. but in case of a duplicate record, binding only one. though DISTINCT keyword is used is SQL Server one if field has different value that show duplicate record on fields QUESTION, OPTIONTXT. I asked my colleague he said SQL Query/Stored Proc is okay. something missing in C#. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My issue got resolved by enabling regional formatting option of the particular textbox. [Click on the link to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVkL9.png)